# How will I convert this snippet (for loop and logic inside it mostly including the for loop) to functional style Java 8

Tags: java

I have the following snippet

```
    public int eraseOverlapIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
        Comparator<int []> c = (e1,e2)->Integer.compare(e1[0],e2[0]);

        Arrays.sort(intervals,c);
        // Get max non overlapping intervals
        int count = 1;
        int []current = intervals[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<intervals.length; i++) {
            int []next = intervals[i];
            if(current[1]<=next[0]) {
                current = next;
                count++;
            } else {
                if(current[1]>next[1]) {
                    current = next;
                }
            }
        }
        return intervals.length-count;
    }
}
```

How do I re-write it in a purely functional Java-8 way?

Comment: You're already using a lambda. What do you mean exactly by "functional Java-8 way"?

Comment: As you have working code, you could ask this on the code review stack exchange site.

Comment: btw, a minor simplification: `Arrays.sort(intervals, Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e[0]));`

Answer (score 0):

Please spend sometime on documentation and explore Java 8 functions, because in this way you will get the solution but you will not learn.
Have a look on below solution It might help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] intervals = {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7}, {6, 8}};

    int count = eraseOverlapIntervals(intervals);

    System.out.println("The number of non-overlapping intervals is: " + count);
}

public static int eraseOverlapIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
    // Sort the intervals by their start values
    Arrays.sort(intervals, Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e[0]));
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final int[][] current = {intervals[0]};
    Arrays.stream(intervals, 1, intervals.length)
            .forEach(next -> {
                if (current[0][1] <= next[0]) {
                    current[0] = next;
                    count.getAndIncrement();
                } else if (current[0][1] > next[1]) {
                    current[0] = next;
                }
            });

    return intervals.length - count.get();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) which introduced in Java 8 for writing in functional way.
The code has re-written in functional for your example , i hope it helps :

```
public int eraseOverlapIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
       Comparator<int[]> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e[0]);
        Arrays.sort(intervals, comparator);
    
        final int[] current = { intervals[0][0], intervals[0][1] };
        final int[] result = { 0 };
        
        Arrays.stream(intervals)
            .skip(1)
            .forEach(next -> {
                if (current[1] <= next[0]) {
                    current[0] = next[0];
                    current[1] = next[1];
                } else {
                    result[0]++;
                    if (current[1] > next[1]) {
                        current[0] = next[0];
                        current[1] = next[1];
                    }
                }
            });
        
        return intervals.length - result[0];

}
```

I've already re-edited my answer for honest compiling error.I hope this answer will be help

Comment: One basic question @Nakip Ali, sometimes you cannot modify a variable while doing a stream. For example if I did count++ in my code above in the stream, it will complain that it needs to be final/effectively final. Why  `current` modifiable in your snippet? I lack that concept too

Comment: It isn't -- try compiling the code.

Comment: What do you mean @tgdavies, current is pointing to different values, it is being modified.

Comment: I mean that the code doesn't compile, because current is not modifiable, as you say. Try compiling the code.

Comment: you are right @tgdavies, this code is incorrect. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: yes , you are right. I wanted give you a hint for solution. Here is the compileable code . i hope it helps for your question.

Comment: @curiousengineer i've already editted my answer.

Comment: So basically use a reference and change the value where the reference is pointing to

Comment: For programming in functional way in java8 , as you said this is one of the solutions for your example , basically :) .

Answer (score -2):

Try the following.

```java
int eraseOverlapIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
    // Get max non overlapping intervals
    class Current { int []current; }
    final Current c = new Current() {{ current = intervals[0]; }};
    return
        intervals.length -
        (int) Stream.of(intervals)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e[0]))
                    .skip(1)
                    .filter(x -> {
                        if(c.current[1] <= x[0]) {
                            c.current = x;
                            return true;
                        } else if (c.current[1] > x[1])
                            c.current = x;
                        return false;
                    })
                    .count();
}
```